# Convert Rounded Corner Rectangle to Rectangle in Visio 2016

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have many Rounded Corner Rectangles in my drawing. How to convert them to Rectangles?

[image]

UPD.

Now I have corner rounding tool:

[image]

But if I select rectangle and press "Conner Rounding" icon nothing is happening. No menu or something like that. Why?

Comment: [Rounding Shape Corners In Visio 2010](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/rounding-shape-corners-in-visio-2010/) - select multiple shapes, open the "Corner Rounding" dialog box, click the "square corner" symbol (top left)

Comment: I have updated question body with my "Conner Rounding" experience.

Comment: I'm using Visio 2019 Pro and had the same issue - the Corner Rounding command seems to do *nothing*!

Answer (score 6):

Master-shape named **Rounded Rectangle** (from **Basic Shapes** stencil) have control which can change rounded corner size !!! Just pull this yellow point to right or to left…
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the corner rounding tool isn't working. However, if you want to change the rounding size for "all" the Rounded Corner Rectangles in your drawing. One way is to update the "Rounded Corner Rectangles" shape in the "Document Stencil".

To do this 
1. Type "Document Stencil" in the "Tell Me" search bar. 
2. Open the Document Stencil. Find the "Rounded Corner Rectangles" shape in that stencil. 
3. Double click to open the shape to edit. 
4. Make changes to the shape to make the "Rounding Size" zero and close the editing window.

You should see that all instances of the "Rounded Corner Rectangles" have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I just right-clicked on the rectangle and selected the "Format Shape" menu item.  Then I select the "Rounding Presets" option and select a rounded corner.

Answer (score 0):

Select the rounded corner rectangle or select multiple if you need to change more than one. Then on the home ribbon select the drop down menu on the change shape icon and select square corner rectangle. All shapes changed without having the change anything on master stencil which would effect the master stencil for the rounded corner rectangle on every page. Meaning if you actually wanted to use a rounded corner rectangle it would be a squared corner rectangle when you dropped it in. [change shape icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nxr3.png)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the answers are for when you already have a rounded corner, but they have a straight corner.  I'm sure they don't want to replace each of the shapes.

If you select the shape, right click and select Format Shape...scroll down in the new window, you'll see "rounding presets".  Select one of the rounded corner options